# Running Android on a PC as a nondeveloper, just to run apps

Tags: windows, android-emulator, emulators, android-pc

I am an Android user running Android 7.0 (Nougat) on a Wiko Sunny 2 Plus device with 4GB internal storage, most of which is taken up by pictures and WhatsApp data. I have purchased this device because I was tired of mobile phones breaking down at home due to carelessness and am now stuck with this cheap model meaning that I now cannot run several nifty apps I had purchased.

However my home computer has about 300GB internal hard drive and I was thinking that even though I cannot carry my computer around the same way as a mobile phone or use touch screen since touch is missing from the screen not use GPS or a back camera nor use the cellular network for phone and messages as it does not have a sim card, I could still download some apps such as edutainment and dictionary apps and use them there.

So, I was wondering, as a nondeveloper, what is the easiest way to download the latest Android OS to your computer, in my case Windows 7 64-bit, and run an Android emulator or full screen tablet app on my computer, so that I can still make use of my purchased apps and what not?

Also, will I be able to use the same Google account name on the emulator without running into problems of conflict with my main smartphone?

Is there an easy emulator setup for nondevelopers, app testers for instance, that does not require a download of all the tools involved?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, [Bluestacks](https://www.bluestacks.com) is the best option for your needs. Particularly suitable for game players, you can run any app on it. No need to download any extra; after downloading Bluestacks on your PC, just log in with your Play Store account and you'll find all of your apps listed.

Answer (score 1):

For non-commercial uses [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) is a great candidate. It is free for personal usage. It supports GApps (Google apps i.e Playstore, Gmail etc). It is also quite faster than the Google's stock emulator which comes with Android studio. For genymotion you need to

1. Make a Genymotion account
2. Download Genymotion for Windows
3. Sign in
4. Download an android OS image
5. Configure the device if you want else run it directly after downloading

Answer (score 0):

You may also wish to try [MEmu - Android emulator](http://www.memuplay.com)

It is highly customizable, yet lightweight with elegant features:

Rich Features:

- Full Android experience with an elegant desktop
- Flexible customization (CPU, memory, resolution, device model, root mode, etc.)

> - Mapping the keyboard/joystick to screen touch for much better game experience
> - Passing through sensor data (e.g. accelerator) to Android, like Microsoft Surface.
> - GPS location simulation, show up wherever you want
> - File sharing between Windows and Android
> - One click to create/clone Android instances

You can setup your Google account just like any other device.

System Requirements:

- Windows Vista/Windows 7 SP1/Windows 8.1/Windows 10
- Intel or AMD CPU (with Virtualization Technology support preferred)
- GPU with OpenGL 2.0+ support
- At least 1 GB free system memory
- At least 2 GB of free disk space under installation path

...and by the way it's absolutely FREE